# Двойное нажатие клавиши при одиночном нажатии

Tags: autohotkey

Чтобы кнопка `q` нажималась 2 раза при нажатии `f`, достаточно написать

```
f::Send {q 2}
return
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `f` сама `f` нажималась 2 раза?

```
f::Send {f 2}
return
```

не работает

Comment: По-моему функционал программы как раз в таком случае ограничен тк такая команда приведёт к бесконечному циклу нажатий f. По моему такое можно реализовать либо переделав как то драйвер клавиатуры, либо купив какую нибудь клавиатуру с поддержкой макросов.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть специальный символ ~:

```
~f::Send f
return
```

Эсли чит не работает всё равно то надо поставить в спячку чтоб успевало

```
~f::
Sleep, 100
Send f   
return
```